# Convert a PHP recursiv function into a PHP public function

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
function copyFolderFiles($src, $dest){
    if(!is_dir($src)){
        return false;
    } 
    if(!is_dir($dest)) { 
        if(!mkdir($dest)) {
            return false;
        }    
    }

    $i = new DirectoryIterator($src);
    foreach($i as $f) {
        if(is_dir($f) != $dest){
            if($f->isFile()) {
                copy($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f->getFilename()));
            } else if(!$f->isDot() && $f->isDir()) {
                copyFolderFiles($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to convert it into a public class recursive function as follows but it didn't work:

```
class systemData {
    public function copyFolderFiles($src, $dest, $n = 0){
        if(!is_dir($src)){
            return false;
        } 
        if(!is_dir($dest)) { 
            if(!mkdir($dest)) {
                return false;
            }    
        }

        $i = new DirectoryIterator($src);
        foreach($i as $f) {
            if(is_dir($f) != $dest){
                if($f->isFile()) {
                    copy($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f->getFilename()));
                } else if(!$f->isDot() && $f->isDir()) {
                    copyFolderFiles($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f), $n+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting `undefined function copyFolderFiles()` referring to `copyFolderFiles($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f), $n+1);`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in order to convert it. The above function is supposed to copy all the files and folders into a particular directory. It works as a standalone function but I would like it as a function in a public class.

I call the function as follows:

```
$systemData = new systemData;
$systemData->copyFolderFiles($documentRoot,$tempFileBackupDir);
```

Comment: have you create an instance/object .? .show how you call the function

Comment: It's now an object so you need to instantiate it first and then call it used OOP syntax

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated my question - `$systemData = new systemData;
$systemData->copyFolderFiles($documentRoot,$tempFileBackupDir);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
copyFolderFiles($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f), $n+1);
```

To

```
$this->copyFolderFiles($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f), $n+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code attempts to call a non existent global function `copyFolderFiles`.

You need to refer to the class method via `$this->`:

```
class systemData
{

    public function copyFolderFiles($src, $dest, $n = 0)
    {
        if(!is_dir($src)){
            return false;
        }
        if(!is_dir($dest)) {
            if(!mkdir($dest)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $i = new DirectoryIterator($src);
        foreach($i as $f) {
            if(is_dir($f) != $dest){
                if($f->isFile()) {
                    copy($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f->getFilename()));
                } else if(!$f->isDot() && $f->isDir()) {
                    //HERE
                    $this->copyFolderFiles($f->getRealPath(), ($dest.'/'. $f), $n+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```